# How should I be able to conisder exclamation mark as different sentence separator beside just full stop

Tags: python, string

I am practicing test and wrote those code but it seems to not consider `!`mark as sentence sperator  but does work for if just use either.

```
for sep in (".", "!", "?")
    sentences = S.split(sep)
    num_of_sentences = len(sentences)
    # print num_of_sentences
    tempDict = {}
    for i, sent in  enumerate(sentences):
        tempDict[i] =  len(sent.split())
    print sentences
    return tempDict[max(tempDict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]]
```

the objective is to return the maximum number of word out of those sentence.
so 
`print sol2("This is one. And this is two. Are you serious? Hi!")`

should output 4

Comment: is this all inside a function? If so, the `return` keyword will only returns the first calculated loop's result, not each result of each loop(the two other loops will not be run). I think we may need the entire function's code.

Comment: Is this [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because it returns after the first loop iteration, in the `return` keyword. It will never run for `"!"`.

Have you considered using regular expressions for this?

```
import re

s = 'This is one. And this is two. Are you serious? Hi!'

sentences = re.findall(r'(.*?)[!.?]', s)  # Split sentences
print(sentences)
# ['This is one', ' And this is two', ' Are you serious', ' Hi']
```

Comment: `re.split("[!.?]", s)` might also work, although it produces an empty sentence at the end. This could be solved with the slice `[:-1]`